# How To Make A public Variable hold changing session values

Tags: php, class, session

hi have a code structure like this

```
public static $userId;
public static $checkUserId;
public $chckUserId;
function __CONSTRUCT(){//Constructor 
    parent::__CONSTRUCT();
    self::$userId = $_SESSION["userid"];//Asssign Current Logged In User's UserId
}
```

this works holding user session then i want to hold one changing session coz i ant to use it in all function of the class i want to be assigned in a public variable , i assigned and worked but not changing what could be the problem?
can u please suggest hw can i implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set the value by reference if you are to hold the changing value.

However, it will be a bad design to do so. Every time you construct an Object, you should so any required assignments inside the constructor.

**Edit:** *Code Added*

```
public static $userId;
public static $checkUserId;
public $chckUserId;
function __CONSTRUCT(){//Constructor 
    parent::__CONSTRUCT();
    self::$userId = &$_SESSION["userid"];//Asssign Current Logged In User's UserId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not much clear about you question but I think the value of global variable `$userId` is not getting changed according to the `session variable`. Well, The `constructor` of the class will be called once whenever you create an object of that class so it is assigning value once

Comment: Actually i have tried public $userChkId and assigned it  from constructor and i tried to change it from object but it's not working will it work ? i mean actually will php support? see that public $chckUserId;
declared i did that for this purpose